# open file dialog not working in vista and 2008 envir

Tags: visual-studio, openfiledialog

i am using Vista . I designed MSi file through Visual Studio 2008 Setup and deployment project in which I added one custom action. In the custom action, I am opening OpenFile dialog. This Open File dialog is not showing mapped drive or network locations. so how can i make the open file dialog to mapthe network drives.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775347

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775347/open-file-dialog-not-working-in-vista-and-2008-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with **Vista User Account Control**. When your installation program is started, the non-admin session of the user is elevated to an admin session. The problem is: [Network drives mapped in the non-admin session of the user do not automatically carry over to the admin session.](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjacks/archive/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx)

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about it. (You can start an elevated command prompt prior to starting your setup project and manually `net use` the drive letters there, but I guess that's not something you can expect your customers to do.)

Related question: [Preserve mapped drive letter information during UAC elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244503)